# How can I use excel addin upload 1G file

Tags: office-addins

I wanted to upload a 1G file via excel addin. but I've met some problems when I was using Office.context.document.getFileAsync().

### Expected Behavior

Returns the entire document file in slices of up to 4194304 bytes (4 MB). I hope the file can be uploaded successfully.

### Current Behavior

But when the file slices to No.256, the error happened.ErrorCode:12007.ErrorMessage:A dialog box is already opened from this host window, so the operation failed.
[errorImg](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/52442516/60559974-34987d80-9d89-11e9-8e82-7de1c2d0a52d.png)

### Steps to Reproduce, or Live Example

the error happened in the function getSlice

```js
function uploadRun() {
    if (isCheckout) {
        $("#msg").empty();
        $('#uploadRun').addClass('disabled');
        $('#uploadCancel').addClass('disabled');
        $('#saveTemp').addClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#msg").empty();
        $('#footer-div .btn-primary').attr('disabled', true);
    }

    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
        Office.FileType.Compressed,
        { },  
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                var myFile = result.value;
                var state = {
                    file: myFile,
                    counter: 0,
                    sliceCount: myFile.sliceCount,
                    fileName: "",
                    result: true,
                    code: "",
                    msg: ""
                };
                getSlice(state);
            } else {
                showMessage(JSMsg["OfficeAddin.msg.00102"], false);
            }
     });
}
function getSlice(state) {
    state.file.getSliceAsync(state.counter, function (result) {
        if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            sendSlice(result.value, state);

        } else if (result.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
            console.log(result);
            showMessage("sliceCounter: " + state.counter + ".ERROR happened. ErrorCode: " + result.error.code + ".ErrorMessage:" + result.error.message, false);
        }else {
            showMessage(JSMsg["OfficeAddin.msg.00102"], false);
        }
    });
}
```